# How reducer without "change" argument should be called (referred)

Tags: state

Usually, when using "reducer pattern" we call reducer a function that takes previous value and change argument that should be applied.

```
reducer: (state, event) => state
```

In some cases, it might be needed to use reducer function that already includes changes and just should be applied to the previous value

```
reducer?: (state) => state
```

I wonder is it ok to refer to this function as `reducer` in both cases, and how they could be distinct on the semantic level?

Answer (score 1):

*While most questions about naming things are opinion-based, given the narrow scope of the question I think this one is answerable.*

---

A reducer function is a concept. It takes stuff, and does stuff to it, then passes the result on.

A reducer that accepts a "change" argument just means the kind of change applied to the `state` is only known at runtime. A reducer that just receives the `state` knows exactly what that change will be at build time.

Fundamentally `reducer?: (state) => state` still takes stuff, does stuff to it, and then passes on the result, therefore it is still a reducer, and there is nothing wrong with calling it as such.